# can't upload multiple files in a form

Tags: php, html

I'm sorry if this is a repost. But I have seen many questions without finding the right answer 
i'm trying to upload multiple files + some information , but if i submit my form with 2 images it goes ok and the script runs perfect when i upload more then 2 or 3 files i get undefined indexs of all the form elements .

**up.php**

```
   /////// Random name generator ////////
function random_name($length) {
$key = '';
$keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
}

   return $key;
}

 //sql//
  require("sql.php");
 //////////
 //!!! some vars !!!//
 //
     $total = count($_FILES['pimages']['name']);
 //
 $foldername = random_name(15);
  $target_dir = "../images/projects/".$foldername."/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["icon"]["name"]);
     $uploadyes = 1;
    $imageType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $saveicon = $target_dir . "icon." .$imageType;

    /////submited form vars /////

  $linkedid = $_POST['lid'];

  $date = date("y.m.d H:i:s");
  $name = $_POST['projectname'];
  $loc = $_POST['location'];
  $type = $_POST['type'];
  $des = $_POST['des'];
  $precara = $_POST['cara'];
  $client = $_POST['client'];
  $col = $_POST['cost'];
  $bua = $_POST['builtup'];

  ////////////////cara slice /////////////
  $caraxarray = explode("," , $precara);
  $cara = base64_encode(serialize($caraxarray));









  echo $imageType ;




  ///////////////////////// Start of the upload check ////////////////////
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($name)) {
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  } 
 }










     // Check if $uploadyes is set to 0 by an error
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
   } else {
      mkdir($target_dir);



      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["icon"]["tmp_name"], $saveicon)) {
             //////////////////////////..........................//////////////////
      // Loop through each file
    $imgext = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$total; $i++) {
     //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['pimages']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $x = $i + 1 ;
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
     //Setup our new file path
  $pimgex = $_FILES['pimages']['name'][$i];

  $pimageType = pathinfo($pimgex,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $newFilePath = $target_dir ."img".$x.".".$pimageType;
  array_push($imgext , "$newFilePath");
      //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

       echo "yeaaaaaah";

     }
   }
 }
   $str = serialize($imgext);
   $sql1 = "INSERT INTO projects (date, name, type, location, icon, imgext, folder, linkedid)
    VALUES ('$date', '$name','$type', '$loc', '$saveicon' , '$str', '$foldername',   '$linkedid')";
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO projectdetails (proname, prolocation, prodes, procara,      client, col, builtarea, linkedid)
 VALUES ('$name', '$loc','$des', '$cara', '$client' , '$col', '$bua',         '$linkedid')";
    mysqli_query($conn ,$sql1);
    mysqli_query($conn ,$sql2);
    mysqli_close($conn);
/////////////////...........................////////////////////////
        header("location:cp.php");
    } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

**projectsuploader.php**

```
   $lkid = random_name(8);
 $tlink = random_name(6);
 require("sql.php");
 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

   $sql1 = "SELECT id, date, name, type, location FROM projects";
   $sql2 = "SELECT id, titleen FROM projectsnav";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
   $types = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);



        //mysqli_close($conn);   

      ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

   <h2>Projects Page</h2>

   <h5>projects</h5>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>#</td>
   <td>Date & Time</td>
   <td>Project name</td>
  <td>Project type</td>
   <td>Project location</td>
 <!--<td>View</td>
 <td>Edit</td>-->
   <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>
   <?php

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     // output data of each row .$row["id"]
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["date"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["type"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["location"]."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='../del.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Remove</a></td>         </tr>";
     }
    } else {
     echo "0 results";
    }
     mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
   </table>
   <h4 id="addproject">Add Project</h3>
   <h4 id="addtype">Add Type </h4>
   <div id="frontlayer">
  <div id="addpro">
  <h2 style="text-align:center;"> add project </h2>
   <form method="POST" action="up.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="50000000">
   id:<input type="text" name="lid" value="<?php echo $lkid ; ?>" readonly>    <br>
    project name:<input type="text" name="projectname"><br>
    Type:<select name="type">

     <?php
     if (mysqli_num_rows($types) > 0){
     while($navrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($types)) {
        echo "<option value='".$navrow['titleen']."'>".$navrow['titleen']."     </option>";
    }
    }else{
        echo "<option>PLEASE ADD TYPES TO DATABASE FIRST!!!!ERROR 0 TYPES IN       DATABASE</option>";
    }

   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>

  </select>
<br>
  location:<input type="text" name="location"><br>
  icon:<input type="file" name="icon" id="icon"><br>
 images:<input type="file" name="pimages[]" id="pimages" multiple><br>
 <input type="hidden" name="sendfiles" value="Send Files" />
 <!--
 ------//////////////------
 ------//////////////------
 ------//////////////------
 -->
 description:<input type="text" name="des"><br>
 caracteristic:<input type="text" name="cara" data-role="tagsinput"><br>
 client:<input type="text" name="client"><br>
Collaborator:<input type="text" name="cost"><br>
Gross Area:<input type="text" name="builtup"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">

</form>
</div>
```

Sorry if it is bad writed i\m begginer , Thanks in advance for anyhelp

Comment: have you tried use '<' instead in this line? `for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {`

Comment: it was already < before i searched and someone said make it <= instead of < so you get the last file uploaded 
the problem is when i click submit and got 3 or 4 photos to upload it  ,it doesnot send data and the php replay the vars not defined .

Comment: Could you send us the error message?

Comment: http://imgur.com/BCBCEBf


first error is 
Notice: Undefined index: pimages in C:\wamp\www\cp\up.php on line 21

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. You are probably reloading "up.php" somewhere, maybe in your "cp.php" or anywhere else.

Comment: Before that, give a try. Remove this line: `header("location:cp.php");`

Comment: i want rly to thank u for your help 
but after removeing header it is still gives same error

Comment: hey there @felippe !
after i tried manythings i found that there is a file makeing this error because it is large one (4mb) sorry for bein annoying i didn't know it was that simple 
but do you know anyway to automatic resize the file because the client will use this won't be able to resize it himself thanks anyway for your help .

Answer (score 0):

The problem were that there was a big file (4mb image) and php was not able to post this size of an image so you have to resize your image before upload ..
and big thanks for Felippe Duarte.